# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: nodejs-npm (missing)

Tags: node.js, npm, dockerfile, npm-install, newman

I'm trying to install `nodeJs`, `npm` and `newman` in my docker image, so I have this in the docker file :

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache nodejs-npm && \
    apk add --update nodejs  && \
    npm install newman --global
```

That gives me this error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  nodejs-npm (missing):
    required by: world[nodejs-npm]
```

I got the command from this question:  [How to install npm in alpine linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1125969/how-to-install-npm-in-alpine-linux)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker image `python:3.6.1-alpine` is based on Alpine Linux v3.4.

According to [alpine packages portal](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=npm&path=&name=&branch=v3.4), `npm` binary can be found in [nodejs](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.4/main/x86_64/nodejs) package in Alpine Linux version 3.4.

So, the final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM python:3.6.1-alpine
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --update nodejs  && \
    npm install newman --global
```